# Insert Image in the middle of the screen Kivy Python

Tags: python, image, kivy

I'm doing a Kivy App but I have an issue. I want to add an image to the screen but I don't know how to put it in the middle of the screen. The fact is that i want the image to work like a float layout (being adaptative to the screen, automatic resizing). I thought it was the same process that is done to center a label or a button, but I've realized it isn't. I insert here the Kivy language code I've been using.

```
<FloatLayout>
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1

    BorderImage:
        # BorderImage behaves like the CSS BorderImage
        border: 10, 10, 10, 10
        source: '../examples/widgets/sequenced_images/data/images/button_white.png'
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size

    Rectangle:
        source: 'etseib.png'
        size: 400, 400
        pos: (400,400)
```

If someone knows how to fix the problem it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center a widget in the middle of a screen, use the [anchor layout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html):

```
Screen:

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'

        Image:
            source: 'logo.png'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 400, 400
            # size: self.texture_size[0] / 2, self.texture_size[1] / 2
            # opacity: 0.1
```

---

Version without anchor layout:

```
Screen:

    Image:
        source: 'image.png'
        keep_ratio: False
        allow_stretch: True
        opacity: 0.8
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.4
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75}
```

Comment: It works! But if i want to be in the center `x` and 0,75 `y` it could be done with anchor layout? I've read that only is possible 'top,bottom,right,left,center' properties, Am I right? If I want to do with a float layout, It would be like this?
`Image:
            source: 'etseib.png'
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.4
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.75}
            opacity: 0.8 ` (the pos_hint seems that doesn't work)

Answer (score -2):

## Add rows:1

```
<FloatLayout>
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1

    BorderImage:
        
        rows: 1
        border: 10, 10, 10, 10
        source: '../examples/widgets/sequenced_images/data/images/button_white.png'
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size

    Rectangle:
        source: 'etseib.png'
        size: 400, 400
        pos: (400,400)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and explain your code a bit, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer